# Richembed not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with discord.js. My current code is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {
  let user = message.mention.users.first();
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField('Bot Info')
  };

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "userinfo"
  }
```

When I try to run it I get the error TypeError: command is not a constructor (line 4)

Any help would be appreciated